# MVVM Navigation fragments switch, but change is not visible

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm

I am trying to build a simple app in Kotlin using MVVM architecture, and I'm struggling with switching fragments. I get it to "change" - on a button press it does nothing, and on a second press it crashes saying "Navigation action/destination MAIN_to_RESULT cannot be found from the current destination RESULT" - so it clearly changed the fragments from MAIN to RESULT, but I still see the MAIN fragment)

Here is my MAIN fragment:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
        binding.setVariable(myViewModel, viewModel)
        viewModel.bnd = binding

        binding.button2.setOnClickListener { viewModel.chng() }
        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener {
            val controller = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
            controller.navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_resultFragment)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
        return binding.root
    }

}
```

OTHER fragment:

```
class ResultFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = ResultFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
        binding.setVariable(BR.myViewModel, viewModel)
        binding.button2.setOnClickListener { viewModel.chng() }

        viewModel.bnd = binding
    }

}
```

MainViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val rps = Repository()
    lateinit var bnd : FragmentMainBinding
    var changing = false
    var SPEED_OF_CHANGING = 100L
    var actualCountedCards = 0
    var numberOfCardsToRotate = 0
    var numberOfRotatedCards = 0
    lateinit var actualCard : Card

    var mainHandler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    private val changeCard = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (changing) {
                actualCard = rps.Cards.random()
                bnd.cardView.setImageResource(actualCard.image)
                actualCountedCards += actualCard.power
                numberOfRotatedCards += 1
                Log.d("tagicek", "${numberOfRotatedCards}/${numberOfCardsToRotate}, ${actualCountedCards}")
                if (numberOfRotatedCards >= numberOfCardsToRotate) {
                    chng()
                    bnd.editTextTextPersonName.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    bnd.submitButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    bnd.button2.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
                mainHandler.postDelayed(this, SPEED_OF_CHANGING)
            }

        }
    }



    fun chng() {
        if (changing == true) {
            mainHandler.removeCallbacks(changeCard)
            actualCountedCards = 0
            numberOfRotatedCards = 0
            bnd.cardView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg)
            changing = false
        } else  {
            numberOfCardsToRotate = (1..51).random()
            mainHandler.post(changeCard)
            changing = true
        }
    }


}
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
        }
    }


}
```

I am pretty sure the problem is with my bindings and views, but I can't wrap my head around it. I have tried probably every positioning of defining the NavController and the different views passed into it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `viewModel.bnd = binding` NEVER store a view in view model!

Comment: Add the code for the nav graph and layout for main activity.